# Issues importing an ontology into Protege

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I have some severe issues importing the "Rhizomik" MPEG7 Ontology in all common ontology Editors. Primarily I tend to work with Protege. 
Import allways leads to several 100 errors. I fixed a few of them. One of the remaining seems to be connected to the following class:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="&mpeg7;SpatioTemporalLocatorType">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;CoordRef"/>
                    <owl:allValuesFrom>
                        <owl:Class>
                            <rdfs:subClassOf>
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;ref"/>
                                    <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                            </rdfs:subClassOf>
                            <rdfs:subClassOf>
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;ref"/>
                                    <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                            </rdfs:subClassOf>
                            <rdfs:subClassOf>
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;spatialRef"/>
                                    <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&mpeg7;boolean"/>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                            </rdfs:subClassOf>
                            <rdfs:subClassOf>
                                <owl:Restriction>
                                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;spatialRef"/>
                                    <owl:minCardinality rdf:datatype="&xsd;nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minCardinality>
                                </owl:Restriction>
                            </rdfs:subClassOf>
                        </owl:Class>
                    </owl:allValuesFrom>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;FigureTrajectory"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;FigureTrajectoryType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;ParameterTrajectory"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;ParameterTrajectoryType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="&mpeg7;MediaTime"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;MediaTimeType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

Is someone in the position to check this class for any logical error?

Kind regards, 
Patrick

Comment: Please provide the errors you're seeing - at least a few of them. Otherwise, giving help is very, very difficult.

Comment: Hi, Protege generates "ErrorXXX" Classes with no further information included. I was able to trace one of them to above xml excerpt. I hoped someone would be able to see a logcal error in the class...

Comment: ErrorXXX indicates an issue with the OWL syntax itself. You should get some logging message from OWLAPI during the parsing.

Comment: It's difficult to inspect this fragment for syntax errors - can you provide the whole ontology, or a complete snippet of this code in the context of the full ontology so that the error can be replicated easily?

Comment: Hi Ignazio, Protege generates no helpful information in its console window. The ontology is reasonably long. Would be a mess to extract all parts involved in above snippet. it is available from here: http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2005/03/Mpeg7-2001.owl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the construction of the axioms. `subClassOf` axioms appear embedded in class usage, but the `rdfs:subClassOf` token is not allowed in those positions (see https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/ for the recognised mappings).

For example, the Error1 URL refers to this axiom:

```
ObjectPropertyRange(<#Mpeg7> <http://org.semanticweb.owlapi/error#Error1>)
```

The corresponding XML is:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="Mpeg7">
    <rdfs:range>
        <owl:Class>
            <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&mpeg7;Mpeg7Type"/>
            <rdfs:subClassOf>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#DescriptionUnit"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;Mpeg7BaseType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#Description"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;CompleteDescriptionType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </rdfs:subClassOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

The intent here is clear, but the anonymous class is intended to be an intersection - it cannot be parsed as such because it is created as nested subclass axioms, which are not valid OWL syntax.

When the above sample is changed to this:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="Mpeg7">
    <rdfs:range>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="&mpeg7;Mpeg7Type"/>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#DescriptionUnit"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;Mpeg7BaseType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#Description"/>
                            <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="&mpeg7;CompleteDescriptionType"/>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

The parsed axiom becomes

```
ObjectPropertyRange(<#Mpeg7>
    ObjectIntersectionOf(
        <http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2005/03/Mpeg7-2001.owl#Mpeg7Type>
        ObjectUnionOf(
            ObjectAllValuesFrom(<#Description> <http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2005/03/Mpeg7-2001.owl#CompleteDescriptionType>)
            ObjectAllValuesFrom(<#DescriptionUnit> <http://rhizomik.net/ontologies/2005/03/Mpeg7-2001.owl#Mpeg7BaseType>)
        )
    )
)
```

I count about 175 similar problems in the file...

Comment: Thanks Ignazio. That helped a lot in understanding what the heck is going on. I meanwhile contacted the author of the ontology. He intends to fix this by himself. For my own project I switched over to another multimedia ontology. Thanks again and have a nice day.